# How to find the sender or source which causes the ko.computable to trigger

Tags: javascript, knockout.js, typescript

I am working on Typescript and KnockoutJs. I am trying to get the sender for knockout computable function. Basically i have two controls, if either of the control's value gets changed then my knockout computable will be called,

```
self.userValue = ko.computed(() => { 
if(self.control1.value())
{

}

if(self.control2.value())
{

}
});
```

It is working fine whenever either of the control's value changes it is calling. But i need to know due to which control's (among the two) value change, made the computable to gets called. I have checked for any sender like property for ko.computable but no use. Please guide me.

Comment: This doesn't really make sense to me, it should be irrelevant which observable triggered a change in the computed observable. Perhaps you're experiencing the XY-problem? *Why* do you think you need this? Or, why not create two seperate observables? Please include a more complete example / repro of how you'd imagine/want this to work.

Comment: @Jeroen yes i am experiencing the XY-Problem, based on values of these two observables i need to call one function, if i took separate computable function the final function would be called more than twice.

Comment: Please then edit your question and create a small repro of your scenario. Your question doesn't currently contain enough information to be able to help you.

Answer (score 0):

You can use subscription and call a function with shared code:

```
function update(sender, newVal) {
     // some shared logic
}


self.control1.value.subscribe((newVal) => {
   // you can add here some specific logic for control1
   update(self.control1, newVal); // may be pass some additional params
});

self.control2.value.subscribe((newVal) => {
   // you can add here some specific logic for control2
   update(self.control2, newVal); // may be pass some additional params
});
```